# My snort graphs have no words

Tags: snort

I just got Security+ certified and stared to care about my network (or use my newly aquired knowledge to make everything better)

I just installed Snort the open source IDS.  I am having one issue  erything working correctly, but the graphs in BASE have no words.

[image]
<sub>(source: [theitguyrox.com](http://www.theitguyrox.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/SnortNoWords.jpg))</sub>

I have googled and found no answers.  Haas anyone else seen anything like this?

Comment: Wild guess mode: you're missing whatever font files BASE thinks it's using for creating the labels.  You might be getting error messages logged in your webserver's error log if this is the case (depending on your webserver, its setup, and how it's running PHP).

Comment: @DerfK It was a font problem. I did some more googling with the errors in the apache log file and found some unhelpful answers. I finally did get it to work after copying font files all over the place. I would make this as the answer, if you can post it without it being a comment.

Comment: Take a couple of minutes, find which of those copies is the one it really needed, then answer it yourself (it'll ask you to wait a bit before marking it as the correct answer).  That would be a much better answer for posterity than my wild guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this on CentOS.
It looks like the PEAR::Image_Graph doesn't use the OS's default font cache.

I had to copy a font file to the Pear folder and edit a config file.

I created a "Fonts" folder in /usr/share/pear/Image/Canvas/

A copied a font file from /usr/share/fonts to the new Fonts folder

```
$ cp /usr/share/fonts/dejavu-lgc/DejaVuLGCSerif.ttf /usr/share/pear/Image/Canvas/Fonts/
```

I then had to edit base_conf.php, I changed the $graph_font_name value to DejaVuLGCSerif.ttf

Answer (score 1):

Like my not below, in 14.04 use:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu /usr/share/php/Image/Canvas/Fonts
```

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't work for me in Ubuntu (12.04.4). I found information [here](http://bullet-bala.blogspot.com/2012/01/fixing-snort-base-graph-with-no-legends.html).

Basically I linked where my fonts were

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu
```

to where PEAR expected them.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu /usr/share/php/Image/Canvas/Fonts
```

Comment: I just re-installed BASE on 14.04. Overcoming various PEAR issues I ran into "my graphs have no words". I searched and come up with my own answer! NOTE: in 14.04, the source font location doesn't have 'ttf-'.